# MySQL php can't connect to localhost, 127.0.0.1 working

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.4

I have a Simple PHP script, that is not able to connect to MySQL.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() . ' ' . mysql_errno());
} else {
    echo "connected";
}
```

When i access the page with url

http://mydomain/1.php

I get error

```
Could not connect: Permission denied 2002
```

If i change "localhost" with "127.0.0.1", it works.

If i run the program from command line, for example

```
php 1.php
```

it connects. To verify the problem, i run

```
[root@server1 ~]# php -r 'var_dump(mysql_connect("localhost:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock", "user", "password"));'
resource(5) of type (mysql link)
[root@server1 ~]# chsh apache --shell /bin/bash
Changing shell for apache.
chsh: Shell not changed.
[root@server1 ~]# su - apache
Last login: Fri Mar 17 02:30:39 CDT 2017 on pts/0
-bash-4.2$ php -r 'var_dump(mysql_connect("localhost:/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock", "user", "password"));'
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Permission denied in Command line code on line 1
bool(false)
-bash-4.2$ ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
ls: cannot access /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock: Permission denied
-bash-4.2$
```

How do i fix this issue, this is CentOS 7 server with default php version. MySQL version is

```
[root@server1 ~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.52-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
[root@server1 ~]#
```

**EDIT:**

This is CentOS 7 Server, SELinux is disabled.

```
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
#
```

Comment: obviously you have to fix the permissions of `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` (and possibly the folders in that path). Also note that this could be a selinux issue. But without seeing the actual permissions this is just blind guessing.

Comment: please run `ls -la /var/lib/mysql/` and `ls -Za /var/lib/mysql/` (as root, not as user apache) and edit the output into your question.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider Schneider Here is the result of the two commands http://pastebin.com/raw/HF0hzQdm  I understand it is a permission issue as user Apache can't access socket, i want to know the correct way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few hours ago (cpanel & cloudlinux)

My simple solution was to modify /etc/my.cnf:

[root@ds1 home]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=28574
**#bind-address=127.0.0.1

bind-address=localhost**
local-infile=0
**[client]

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

host=localhost**
[root@ds1 home]#

Answer (score 1):

localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not the same for mysql, you need a grant for each of them.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by running

```
chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you might have created the user which is bound with **127.0.0.1**. 
Try one thing create another user like this in mysql.

```
create user 'my_user'@'localhost' identified by 'mypassword';
```

and grant same privileges to this user as the earlier one.

Note : *You can keep the same username, or you can delete the earlier one and create the new one, its up to you*.

Comment: How is the mysql client supposed to do the login when it can't even access the file socket?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here, as he says his client is able to access mysql with 127.0.0.1 but not localhost.

Comment: If this were a permission problem inside mysql the error message would look like this: `Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

Comment: Yeah you got a point. Hi @HostOnNet can you please share whether apparmor is enabled or not. If yes can you please share the configuration for that.

Comment: This is CentOS 7 server. SELinux is disabled.  

  # sestatus
    SELinux status:                 disabled
  #

Comment: This.  Additionally, whenever you specify "localhost" or "localhost:port" as server, the MySQL client library will override this and try to connect to a local socket (named pipe on Windows), so if your not set up to use sockets/pipes then you have to specify 127.0.0.1